# Could not locate a valid MSVC version

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to compile a project from command prompt to open from visual studio.
The project needed CMake, Python and Visual Studio 2015 to run, i have downloaded and installed all of those. I am trying to run a .cmd file "get-deps.cmd" file but it is unable to locate the valid MSVC version. Can someone help.
Below is the screen sample.

`D:\pT1\polarisdeps>get-deps.cmd c:\opt\polarisdeps_vs2015`
`BASEDIR=c:\opt\polarisdeps_vs2015`
`1 file(s) copied.`
`Could not locate a valid MSVC version.`

Comment: Did you run it inside the Visual Studio 2015 command prompt? Or just plain cmd?

Comment: plain command command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cl.exe` and similar visual studio commands are not in PATH. This means that you cannot execute them in the familiar manner (except if you add them to PATH) using CMD.

You'll have to open the Visual Studio 2015 Command Prompt to be able to access `cl.exe` and similar commands. Then, inside the VS 2015 command prompt, you can execute the `get-deps.cmd` script.

Comment: Thank you. I opened the Visual Studio 2015 Developer Command Prompt and it works. Thanks alot